Question about the Fisher information metric
suppose we have the two one dimensional gaussian probability distribution functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with parameters $P=(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $Q=(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ so we know that we can give the manifold structure to this which will be the $H=\{(\mu,\sigma)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:\sigma>0\}$ which is the upper half plane and we do it by the map so that we can use the geometric properties of the mapped space which in our case is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
In the book, it says that the distance between the $P$ and $Q$ which are parameters is computed using the Fisher information metric which is the minimum length of all the piecewise smooth curves joining $P$ and $Q$ okay and it also says that the Euclidean distance may not be appropriate to find the distance between $P$ and $Q$ since it will not give the accurate similarity but my question is if $P$ and $Q$ are in the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ only and we mapped all the pdfs to this space using the homeomorphism map then why can't we use the metric of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I mean what is the benefit of the mapping if I cannot use the metric of the space?

Since $H$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is absolutely no mathematical problem in pulling back the Euclidean Riemannian metric tensor on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $H$.
However, the submanifold $H$ is representing probability measures, and this additional piece of information is not really captured by the Euclidean metric tensor. Let me try to explain it with reference to estimation theory.
Imagine you are investigating a random phenomenon, and you have theoretical reasons to believe that the probability measure describing is a Normal distribution, and thus can be identified with a point in $H$.
Then, you go and make some measurements (assuming independence) leading to a set of outcomes $(x_{1},\cdots x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and you want to use these outcomes to determine the "true" probability measures generating the outcomes.
Practically, you want a map $\xi\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image lies in $H$ (the space parametrizing all possible Normal distributions among which the "true" probability distribution is living). Mathematically, this map is a vector-valued random variable, and it is often referred to as an estimator because it helps estimating the parameters of the "true" probability measure.
A typical example would be that in which the first component of $\xi$ is the sample mean
$$
\hat{\mu}(x_{1},\cdots , x_{n}):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j},
$$
while the second component is the sample variance
$$
\hat{\sigma}(x_{1},\cdots , x_{n}):=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j} - \hat{\mu})^{2}.
$$
How can we "measure" how good is this choice?
Well, since $\xi$ is a random variable, we may investigate its covariance matrix whose components read
$$
(\mathrm{Cov}_{P^{n}}(\xi))_{jk}=\mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}\left((\xi^{j} -\mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}(\xi^{j}))((\xi^{k} -\mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}(\xi^{k}))\right)=\mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}\left(\xi^{j}\,\xi^{k}\right) - \mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}\left(\xi^{j}\right)\, \mathbb{E}_{P^{n}}\left(\xi^{k}\right).
$$
Note that $P^{n}$ is the probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ you obtain by taking the $n$-time direct product of the single normal distribution $P$. This is an assumption we make because we assume that the data we measured come from an i.i.d. situation.
The covariance matrix is a positive matrix measuring how correlated are the components of our estimator, and the celebrated Crámer-Rao inequality, states that the covariance matrix $\mathrm{Cov}_{P^{n}}(\xi)$ is always greater or equal (in the matrix sense) to a matrix which is precisely the inverse of the Fisher-Rao metric tensor at the point $P^{n}$.
Then, we can compute the covariance matrix for the sample mean and sample variance, and see that it is precisely equal to the inverse of the Fisher-Rao metric tensor, so that it saturates the Crámer-Rao inequality. In this sense, we say that the sample mean and sample variance provide an efficient estimator.
This surprising marriage between geometry and statistics is one of the reasons why the Fisher-Rao metric tensor is preferred to the Euclidean one.
Note that the Crámer-Rao inequality works not only for Normal distributions, and for all unbiased estimators (some additional technicalities must be specified, though).
